# Protractor - webdriver-manager start gives (RunTimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind)

Tags: protractor

When i use the webdriver-manager start command to start the server it gives me the below error. I installed the protractor and webdriver-manager globally

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:182)
            at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$1.launch(GridLauncherV3.java:238)
            at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:99)
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
            at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
            at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
            at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:298)
            at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
            at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
            at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:431)
            at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:180)
            ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this will happen when the port is already in use. Webdriver use port:4444 as default. Seems like 4444 port is in already in use. Try to use a different port.

Can start web driver with the different port with the following command:

`webdriver-manager start --seleniumPort=XXXX e.g(4445)`